# Wordpress: Changing the "slug" of an individual custom post type post

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, slug

I have a custom post type in Wordpress.  For a particular custom post, I'd like to change the slug of the custom post's permalink to be different than what is generated from the title. There is a field in the permalink menu to do this for a page or post, but this field is missing from the custom post type.  Any ideas on how to be able to change this?

ANSWERED IN Vijay Haradah's comment below.

Comment: Below the post title input you see the permalink with the edit link, can't you use that and edit your slug? if not then you can use quick edit in the admin table to change the slug.

Comment: Could you please let me know what kind of permalink structure you would like?

Comment: @VijayHardaha Thanks! I did find that I can edit the slug using quick edit in the admin table.  For whatever reason, there is no edit link for the permalink when editing the full custom post, which threw me off.

Comment: @InForest `publicly_queryable` or `public` is set to false, then you won't see the permalink with the edit button below the title field in the classic editor. If that is not the case and you're using block editor and `public` is true then you'll find the permalink section in the settings panel there you can change the slug.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this at the moment of registering the CPT or filtering.

```
function wp_unique_post_slug( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent ) {
if ( in_array( $post_status, array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ), true )
    || ( 'inherit' === $post_status && 'revision' === $post_type ) || 'user_request' === $post_type
) {
    return $slug;
}

/**
 * Filters the post slug before it is generated to be unique.
 *
 * Returning a non-null value will short-circuit the
 * unique slug generation, returning the passed value instead.
 *
 * @since 5.1.0
 *
 * @param string|null $override_slug Short-circuit return value.
 * @param string      $slug          The desired slug (post_name).
 * @param int         $post_ID       Post ID.
 * @param string      $post_status   The post status.
 * @param string      $post_type     Post type.
 * @param int         $post_parent   Post parent ID.
 */
$override_slug = apply_filters( 'pre_wp_unique_post_slug', null, $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent );
if ( null !== $override_slug ) {
    return $override_slug;
}

global $wpdb, $wp_rewrite;

$original_slug = $slug;

$feeds = $wp_rewrite->feeds;
if ( ! is_array( $feeds ) ) {
    $feeds = array();
}

if ( 'attachment' === $post_type ) {
    // Attachment slugs must be unique across all types.
    $check_sql       = "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND ID != %d LIMIT 1";
    $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $slug, $post_ID ) );

    /**
     * Filters whether the post slug would make a bad attachment slug.
     *
     * @since 3.1.0
     *
     * @param bool   $bad_slug Whether the slug would be bad as an attachment slug.
     * @param string $slug     The post slug.
     */
    $is_bad_attachment_slug = apply_filters( 'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_attachment_slug', false, $slug );

    if ( $post_name_check
        || in_array( $slug, $feeds, true ) || 'embed' === $slug
        || $is_bad_attachment_slug
    ) {
        $suffix = 2;
        do {
            $alt_post_name   = _truncate_post_slug( $slug, 200 - ( strlen( $suffix ) + 1 ) ) . "-$suffix";
            $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $alt_post_name, $post_ID ) );
            $suffix++;
        } while ( $post_name_check );
        $slug = $alt_post_name;
    }
} elseif ( is_post_type_hierarchical( $post_type ) ) {
    if ( 'nav_menu_item' === $post_type ) {
        return $slug;
    }

    /*
     * Page slugs must be unique within their own trees. Pages are in a separate
     * namespace than posts so page slugs are allowed to overlap post slugs.
     */
    $check_sql       = "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type IN ( %s, 'attachment' ) AND ID != %d AND post_parent = %d LIMIT 1";
    $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $slug, $post_type, $post_ID, $post_parent ) );

    /**
     * Filters whether the post slug would make a bad hierarchical post slug.
     *
     * @since 3.1.0
     *
     * @param bool   $bad_slug    Whether the post slug would be bad in a hierarchical post context.
     * @param string $slug        The post slug.
     * @param string $post_type   Post type.
     * @param int    $post_parent Post parent ID.
     */
    $is_bad_hierarchical_slug = apply_filters( 'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_hierarchical_slug', false, $slug, $post_type, $post_parent );

    if ( $post_name_check
        || in_array( $slug, $feeds, true ) || 'embed' === $slug
        || preg_match( "@^($wp_rewrite->pagination_base)?\d+$@", $slug )
        || $is_bad_hierarchical_slug
    ) {
        $suffix = 2;
        do {
            $alt_post_name   = _truncate_post_slug( $slug, 200 - ( strlen( $suffix ) + 1 ) ) . "-$suffix";
            $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $alt_post_name, $post_type, $post_ID, $post_parent ) );
            $suffix++;
        } while ( $post_name_check );
        $slug = $alt_post_name;
    }
} else {
    // Post slugs must be unique across all posts.
    $check_sql       = "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type = %s AND ID != %d LIMIT 1";
    $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $slug, $post_type, $post_ID ) );

    $post = get_post( $post_ID );

    // Prevent new post slugs that could result in URLs that conflict with date archives.
    $conflicts_with_date_archive = false;
    if ( 'post' === $post_type && ( ! $post || $post->post_name !== $slug ) && preg_match( '/^[0-9]+$/', $slug ) ) {
        $slug_num = (int) $slug;

        if ( $slug_num ) {
            $permastructs   = array_values( array_filter( explode( '/', get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ) ) );
            $postname_index = array_search( '%postname%', $permastructs, true );

            /*
            * Potential date clashes are as follows:
            *
            * - Any integer in the first permastruct position could be a year.
            * - An integer between 1 and 12 that follows 'year' conflicts with 'monthnum'.
            * - An integer between 1 and 31 that follows 'monthnum' conflicts with 'day'.
            */
            if ( 0 === $postname_index ||
                ( $postname_index && '%year%' === $permastructs[ $postname_index - 1 ] && 13 > $slug_num ) ||
                ( $postname_index && '%monthnum%' === $permastructs[ $postname_index - 1 ] && 32 > $slug_num )
            ) {
                $conflicts_with_date_archive = true;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Filters whether the post slug would be bad as a flat slug.
     *
     * @since 3.1.0
     *
     * @param bool   $bad_slug  Whether the post slug would be bad as a flat slug.
     * @param string $slug      The post slug.
     * @param string $post_type Post type.
     */
    $is_bad_flat_slug = apply_filters( 'wp_unique_post_slug_is_bad_flat_slug', false, $slug, $post_type );

    if ( $post_name_check
        || in_array( $slug, $feeds, true ) || 'embed' === $slug
        || $conflicts_with_date_archive
        || $is_bad_flat_slug
    ) {
        $suffix = 2;
        do {
            $alt_post_name   = _truncate_post_slug( $slug, 200 - ( strlen( $suffix ) + 1 ) ) . "-$suffix";
            $post_name_check = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $check_sql, $alt_post_name, $post_type, $post_ID ) );
            $suffix++;
        } while ( $post_name_check );
        $slug = $alt_post_name;
    }
}

/**
 * Filters the unique post slug.
 *
 * @since 3.3.0
 *
 * @param string $slug          The post slug.
 * @param int    $post_ID       Post ID.
 * @param string $post_status   The post status.
 * @param string $post_type     Post type.
 * @param int    $post_parent   Post parent ID
 * @param string $original_slug The original post slug.
 */
return apply_filters( 'wp_unique_post_slug', $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug );
```

}

Credits and Docs can be found at:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unique_post_slug/

Hope that can point you into something.